# Dockerization of Play Application

Tags: docker, playframework

I want to dockerize my play application
here is my Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8 AS SCRATCH

WORKDIR /

ADD . .

EXPOSE 9000

CMD bin/activator run -Dconfig.file=conf/application.conf
```

Problem I am facing is that my dependencies are getting downloaded again and again when I execute docker run command
I don’t want this to happen i can understand that the error might because of `ADD . .` but i don’t know what to do

Comment: This happens because you build app from scratch inside container every time. You need either build it locally and add jar or zip inside container, or use docker multi stage build: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: https://ilhicas.com/2019/04/23/Play-Framework-Docker-jib-sbt.html

Comment: are multistage builds also depends on how the activator run script is written? @ IvanKurchenko

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO community!
As I mentioned in the comment section, this happens because you build an app from scratch inside a container every time.
One of the easiest options to go - use [Docker plugin from sbt-native packager](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html), in order to avoid manual work with Docker file.

The final configuration of `build.sbt` depends on the details of your Play app, but you can start by adding:

```
enablePlugins(DockerPlugin)
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(9000) //expose default Play port
```

and building app container with `sbt docker:publishLocal` command.

Comment: as far as I know, I think Scratch is just a name for this stage

Comment: I have read the article which you sent on the multistage build but I didn’t get much idea like I know I have to break ```ADD . .``` command so that I can take advantage of cached layer but I am thinking there should be some standard way for dockerizing the Play Application

Comment: @Lazy_Nerd I revisited my prev comments, that's why suggested to use native packager.

Comment: @Lazy_Nerd Please, leave up-vote or accept answer if it was somehow helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am still trying your approach that's why I could not get time to upvote your answer
Thanks btw maybe you will not able to see my upvote because of my reputation score but I upvoted you now